# Unable to install Kcachegrind on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, kcachegrind

I want to start knowing kcachegrind for profiling my php stuff.

Tried with

```
sudo apt-get install kcachegrind
```

and

```
sudo apt-get -f install kcachegrind
```

but I always get

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    kcachegrind : Depends: kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed
```

Am I missing something?

Many thanks.

Comment: So, what happens if you try to install kde-runtime?

Comment: requires another dep, then another, then another...

Comment: Is there a way to install every deps in one command/flag?

Comment: That should be done automatically. This is strange. Can't say more, since I do not use a debian based distribution but openSUSE, which is rpm based instead.

Comment: I'd expect `apt-get install` to list all packages it plans to install. Idn't that the case? If so just specify all of those on the command line. It should tell you which one does not have a satisfied dependency or requirement. I still remember those times when people claimed that apt was so much better than rpm/zypper because of resolving much better. These days I hear endless problems in that point with apt. Maybe it has fallen behind...

Comment: I'd recommend to look for a gnome like substitute for kcachegrind or setup a KDE based distro in a virtual machine (kubuntu, for example). It seems that the kcachegrind package will require a lot of underlying kde-libraries. On your original question, the dependency resolver in apt detects some problem with kde-runtime and kcachegrind, maybe different versions. Are you installing both from the same source repository?

Comment: Yes, I definitively moved to Hxprof. Works like a charm.

Comment: There's also this trouble-shooting guide to `apt-get`: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies (I'm using kcachegrind on ubuntu 12.04 fwiw)